# Request to URL defined with ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url annotation is done with HTTP/1.0

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am using auth-url and auth-signin annotation for authenticating access to app. Problem is that request to URL defined with auth-url is always done with HTTP/1.0 and not with HTTP/1.1 as expected. From logs you can see that all other requests are done with HTTP/1.1.

Version used: nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.19

Logs from ELB:

```
2017-11-30T14:28:30.606436Z dev-sandbox-2cb4 201.137.96.59:58692 10.10.0.101:80 0.000044 0.031215 0.000039 302 302 0 154 "GET https://example.net:443/testing/ HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
2017-11-30T14:28:30.623944Z dev-sandbox-2cb4 24.134.104.23:40704 10.10.7.144:80 0.000029 0.01263 0.000068 401 401 0 21 "GET https://example.net:443/oauth2/auth HTTP/1.0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
2017-11-30T14:28:30.699239Z dev-sandbox-2cb4 201.137.96.59:58692 10.10.3.6:80 0.000028 0.001223 0.000046 302 302 0 395 "GET https://example.net:443/oauth2/start?rd=https://example.net/testing/ HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
```

Annotation:

```
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start"
```

Problem is that in the environment I need to use only 1.1 is allowed.

Is this something to be expected or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be solved by adding

```
proxy_http_version          1.1;
```

under `location = {{ $authPath }}` block in nginx ingress template.

See https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/1787.